# Find files by extension recursive, exclude folders, sort result by modified date

Tags: macos, bash

I need to find files matching the following criteria:

- extension is `md`
- within folder `.` and all subfolders
- exclude all `node_modules` folders
- sort by modified date, latest first across all results

I tried this but I guess my exclude for `node_modules` is wrong as I still get results including `node_modules` folders when including the fragment `\( ! -iname "node_modules" \)`:

```
find $PWD -name "*.md" \( ! -iname "node_modules" \) -print0 | xargs -0 ls -laht
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work but it is very slow when having a lot of subfolders. So I'm open for better solutions:

```
find "$PWD" -name "*.md" ! -path '*/node_modules/*' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -laht
```

**Update:**
Based on the [hint from Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/questions/1478543/find-files-by-extension-recursive-exclude-folders-sort-result-by-modified-date/1478551#comment2228881_1478551) regarding `-prune`, I came up with this solution which is much faster now:

```
find "$PWD" -name "node_modules" -prune -o -name "*.md" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -laht -P 1
```

Comment: No time for a good quality answer now, therefore just a hint: research `-prune`.

Comment: Nice. Two issues: (1) `$PWD` should be [double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). (2) When there are many results, `xargs` may run two or more `ls` processes in sequence. Each `ls` will sort independently, so most likely the overall result will not be sorted as a whole.

Comment: Thanks, I mitigated (2) by adding `-P 1` as `xargs` option.

Comment: I think `-P 1` in your code will be passed as an option to `ls`, am I wrong? If you move it before `ls` then it will be an option to `xargs`. Even if it changes anything (`1` is the default value in GNU `xargs`, I don't know macOS), it doesn't solve the problem I mentioned. (You may be aware, you used the word "mitigated" instead of "solved"). A way to make a single `ls` "sort" (semi-)arbitrarily many files is to copy/hardlink/symlink them into a separate directory and invoke `ls` for the entire directory (with `-L` if needed). There may be "maximum number of files per directory" limit though.